# How to access keys in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, key

How could i access keys in pandas, for example in the following dataframe my key is "d" ,
i'm trying to use `print(df['d']['latitude'])` but says key error, when i list the dataframe keys with df.keys() is only "d" , how can i access latitude and longitude?

```
Index(['_id', 'd'], dtype='object')
0             {'latitude': 35.685, 'longitude': 139.7514}
1                  {'latitude': 60.0, 'longitude': -95.0}
2       {'latitude': 54.94499999999999, 'longitude': -...
3       {'latitude': 41.32740000000001, 'longitude': -...
4       {'latitude': 42.83330000000001, 'longitude': 1...
                              ...
6000         {'latitude': 41.1412, 'longitude': -73.2637}
6001                {'latitude': 52.5, 'longitude': 5.75}
6002    {'latitude': 1.3667000000000087, 'longitude': ...
6003         {'latitude': 41.1412, 'longitude': -73.2637}
6004    {'latitude': 45.16669999999999, 'longitude': 2...
Name: d, Length: 6005, dtype: object
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to load the **json list** items to **dataframe**. A sample code is give below..

```
import json
from pandas import json_normalize

data = """
            {
            "coordinates":
                    [
                    {'latitude': 35.685, 'longitude': 139.7514},
                    {'latitude': 41.1412, 'longitude': -73.2637},
                    {'latitude': 60.0, 'longitude': -95.0},
                    {'latitude': 52.5, 'longitude': 5.75}
                    ],
            "status": ["ok"]
            }
        """
data_dict = json.loads(data)
df = json_normalize(data_dict["coordinates"])
df
```

Data Frame will be:

| index | latitude | longitude |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 35.685 | 139.7514 |
| 1 | 41.1412 | -73.2637 |
| 2 | 60.0 | -95.0 |
| 3 | 52.5 | 5.75 |

if we print latitude only

```
df2["latitude"]
```

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 35.6850 |
| 1 | 41.1412 |
| 2 | 60.0000 |
| 3 | 52.5000 |

Name: latitude, dtype: float64

Comment: Hello Thanks , I tried to load my data into json, but throws a Typerror the json should be str bytes etc etc not a cursor. doesn't work for me, but seems useful though, Thanks

Comment: where did you got the Type error actually? Is it raised while loading dict(json) to dataframe or dataframe to dict(json)

Comment: Hey , thanks, i solved already by my own , the  solution was to put the whole mongodb pointer into a new json, then load the json in the dataframe and more easy to call the keys, worked with d.latitude and that;s it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access `latitude` (for example) for a specific index you may use

```
df['d'].iloc[index]['latitude']
```

you should be able to iterate like so

```
[x['latitude'] for x in df['d'].tolist()]
```

Comment: Hello Thanks, I tested unfortunately is not working, tried with different index and doesn't work ,  i just want to access latitude and longitude Thanks again.